# Credit card number mismatch with credit card type

Tags: api, ce-1.8.1.0, payment, soap

I am using mage api to genertae order but when i generate order using shoppingCartOrder function it gives error "Credit card number mismatch with credit card type."

```
$proxy->shoppingCartPaymentMethod($sessionId, $quoteId, array(
                    'po_number'    => 'null',
                    'method'       => 'paypal_direct',
                    'cc_cid'       => '123',
                    'cc_owner'     => 'test',
                    'cc_number'    => '4111111111111111',
                    'cc_type'      => 'VI',
                    'cc_exp_year'  => '2022',
                    'cc_exp_month' => '12'
                    )); 

    $cart_order_result=$proxy->shoppingCartOrder($sessionId, $quoteId);
```

Comment: I've seen this myself with older version of Magento and Paypal Direct. This must be a bug with Paypal.

Answer (score 1):

The credit card number is checked against the type using regex, this can be found in `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc::validate`

But for visa it uses the regex `'VI'  => '/^4[0-9]{12}([0-9]{3})?$/',` so what it needs is a 4 followed by 12 digits, with an optional 3 digits at the end.

It appears that your number is valid but for some reason the type is still the default `OT` in the validate code. I would suggest you look into this regex loop to see what is actually happening with your value.